# Verilog : Combinatorial logic for variable length register

Tags: for-loop, concatenation, verilog, sha1

I am presnetly learning Verilog. As a first project, I decided to go with a SHA-1 brute forcer.

SHA-1 require a fixed length input of 512 bits.  The data input can be variable length, so few manipulation must be done to get a valid 512 bits block. Basically, for a block smaller than 512 bits, the first 448 bits of the data block must be a concatenation of these 3 :

1. Variable length data
2. 0x01 (8 bits)
3. 0 padding

My first step in generating that data was to make a module that could generate the variable length input. Let say I want to brute-force up to 8 characters, that module will output a 64 bits bus (8 bits x 8 chars)   and also a 8 bits bus indicating what digit is valid.

For instance, the string "test" would be represented this ways :

- data : 0x0000000074657374
- valid_digits : 0b00001111

Starting with that, my issue is that I have problem to do a proper concatenation based on valid_digits and keep things configurable.

Here's a piece of code that works, but is hardcoded for 8 digits inputs. I am sure I could use a loop there, but can't achieve to get the right syntax for it.

```
    assign data_block[511:64] = 
        ( valid_digits == {1{1'b1}} ) ? {chars[7:0], 8'h1, 432'b0 } :
        ( valid_digits == {2{1'b1}} ) ? {chars[15:0], 8'h1, 424'b0 } :
        ( valid_digits == {3{1'b1}} ) ? {chars[23:0], 8'h1, 416'b0 } :
        ( valid_digits == {4{1'b1}} ) ? {chars[31:0], 8'h1, 408'b0 } :
        ( valid_digits == {5{1'b1}} ) ? {chars[39:0], 8'h1, 400'b0 } :
        ( valid_digits == {6{1'b1}} ) ? {chars[47:0], 8'h1, 392'b0 } :
        ( valid_digits == {7{1'b1}} ) ? {chars[55:0], 8'h1, 384'b0 } :
        ( valid_digits == {8{1'b1}} ) ? {chars[63:0], 8'h1, 376'b0 } :
        0;
```

Anybody has an idea what syntax I should use to re-write that with a loop and a parameter called : MAX_CHAR_CNT that would contain the maximum length of my data input ? I'd like to keep this a combinatorial logic function.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my stab at it - may not be perfect, but seems to simulate OK. If nothing else, in might give you a start.

```
module test(valid_digits,chars, data_block);
  parameter MAX_CHAR_CNT = 8;
  input [MAX_CHAR_CNT-1:0] valid_digits;
  input [8*MAX_CHAR_CNT-1:0] chars;
  output reg [511:0] data_block;

  wire [511:0] data_lines [MAX_CHAR_CNT-1:0];

  genvar i;
  integer x;

  generate
    for (i=0; i<MAX_CHAR_CNT; i=i+1) begin:DATA
      assign data_lines[i] = {chars[8*(i+1)-1:0], 8'h1, {(512-8*(2+i)){1'b0}}};
    end
  endgenerate

  always @(*) begin:CONN
    data_block = 0;
    for (x=0; x<MAX_CHAR_CNT; x=x+1) begin
      //if (valid_digits == {(x+1){1'b1}}) data_block <= data_lines[x];
        if (valid_digits == (9'b1<<(x+1))-1) data_block = data_lines[x];
    end
  end

endmodule
```

(See http://www.edaplayground.com/x/FiD for simulation)

---

Re: the use of Non-Blocking Assignments (NBA's, `<=`) - NBAs can be used for either sequential or combinational logic. For an non-clocked `always` block assigning to a single value, there should be no difference - the final assignment will be the one used. While I like the NBA in this specific instance, either operator will work, so I've switched it to a BA for both clarity and peer pressure. :)

Comment: Why are you using NBA (`<=`) in the `CONN` block? If its suppose to be combinational, it should use blocking assignment(`=`).

Comment: Thanks for that !  The output of the simulation gives exactly what I need (except the padding that is 512 instead of 448).  Even though it works, that piece of code is not combinatorial logic only. Also, when I try synthesizing it with XST, I am getting an error saying that "x is not a constant" in the CONN block if-statement

Comment: @Unn - you can use NBA's for combinatorial logic; see my addendum in my answer.

Comment: @Pier-YvesLessard - I've edited my answer slightly, which should remove that error; I tried the original in Quartus 13.0 and saw the same error as you, and no longer see it with the change. Quartus also confirms that the code results in purely combinaltional logic (see my addendum). I've also updated the EDAplayground code with the corrected answer if you want to sim it :)

Comment: @wilcroft - you can use NBA for comb logic, however you *should* use blocking. Blocking for comb logic, non-blocking for sequential assignment (i.e. DFF and latches).

Comment: @Greg - I'll cede to the style point (and the general usage). I like the NBA for my own personal understanding (to ensure only the final assignment to`data_block` gets used), but for the clarity of others/the OP, I've switched to BAs.

Comment: @wilcroft -  Its a best practice guideline, not a style preference. I suggest reading [Nonblocking Assignments in Verilog Synthesis, Coding Styles That Kill!](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf) ; check out other papers on Blocking vs Non-Blocking too. FYI: it is a common interview question

Comment: @wilcroft - I confirm that your solution produces the expected result. Thank you.